# How to write a loop in Rust with a decreasing range including the 0?

Tags: loops, for-loop, rust

I need to write a loop in Rust that runs its body from a value down to and including `n = 0`.  At first, I wrote it like this:

```
for n in max..0 {
    // ...
}
```

However, it just runs until `n = 1`.

The best alternative I can think of is this:

```
let mut n = max;
loop {
    // ...

    if n == 0 {
        break;
    }
    n -= 1;
}
```

This solution is really clumsy and doesn't satisfy me. Is there a better way of writing that loop, e.g. a for-loop with a range including the right boundary value of the `..`?

Comment: `for n in (0..max).rev()`